# Символ "+" в языке SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Сейчас осваиваю язык sql в Access. Когда пишу там запрос, то использую пробелы. К примеру, выбираю имена из таблицы `SELECT name FROM users`, но видел другой вид `SELECT+name+FROM+users`.
Но при написании такого запроса в Access выдает ошибку. Если же написать
`SELECT+name FROM+users`, то СУБД выдает верный результат, как это понимать?
Когда и в каких случаях можно использовать символ "+", и как можно иначе избежать пробелов в запросе?

Comment: Вроде бы access - это не mysql...

Comment: К тому же непонятно, чем пробелы в запросе помешали? Уж не с веб-страницы ли ты их пересылаешь?

Answer (score 5):

`+` используется для конкатенации строковых выражений.
Код `SELECT+name FROM+users` работать не должен, если сам оператор не формируется как строка символов в динамическом `SQL`.

Answer (score 1):

В `SQL` знак `+` описан только как оператор сложения для чисел и интервалов времени.

Всё остальное возможное применение - на усмотрение конкретных реализаций. Как оператор `select 'foo' + 'bar'` может:

- быть поводом попытаться привести строки к числами и получить 0 в результате (mysql, sqlite)
- оператором конкатенации строк (ms sql, если верить сервису [sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com))
- выдавать ошибку за использование не с числами (oracle, опять же по результатам проверки sqlfidle)
- ответить, что не знает такого оператора (postgresql - потому что операторы можно добавлять самостоятельно)
- что-нибудь ещё - потому что это не регламентировано стандартом

По ms access не знаю, мне негде проверить, какую реализацию выбрали для него. Вероятно так же как для ms sql.

Вместо пробелов символ `+` в SQL использоваться не может. SQL требует разделение ключевых слов именно пробельными символами.